# Date Formatting {Year} {Month Number}

Tags: sql, dbt

I'm trying to add a date column in the following format: {Year} {Month Number} 2021-01. If possible, also a column with the month name: 2021 Jan. Right now what I did is, which gives [YYYY/MM/DD]

`CAST(l_i.created_date as DATE) as Date`

Comment: tag your dbms , also why not have a `date` type column and you can just show month and year easily

Comment: You can insert values with date datatype and later can always format in whatever format you need while selecting data.

Comment: How do I get Only the month and year 2021-01 and 2021 Jan, I do have the date type column which is listed above, but i want to format it a different way

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with this way:

```
SELECT
  CAST(l_i.created_date as DATE) as date_column,
  DATE_FORMAT(CAST(l_i.created_date as DATE), '%Y %m %Y-%m') as formatted_date,
  DATE_FORMAT(CAST(l_i.created_date as DATE), '%Y %b') as month_name
FROM
  table_name l_i
```